# Is a, b = b, a + b good python?

Tags: python, coding-style

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

I picked up this coding style from 'Building Skills in Python'.  Coming from PHP and Obj-C this type of multi-variable assignment wasn't available (at least not that I've seen). But it seems more logical to me.  Afterall, why should I have to assign 'a' to a 'holding variable' before it is replaced.

**Question is, is this coding style pythonic?**

Here's a sample Fibonacci program:

```
a, b = 1, 2
output = str(a)
while b<=100:
    output = output + " " + str(b)
    a, b = b, a + b

print output
```

**And, what's the best way you found helped you write more pythonic code?**

Comment: Yes, it’s pythonic. `output = output + " " + str(b)` is less so, though. You can start with `+=` for the smallest change to make a big difference.

Comment: You could add spaces around `<=`, so it would be not just pythonic, but well-formatted.

Comment: @mhlester Whatever, Python doesn't even have a **proper** type-system..

Comment: @mhlester I'm glad we agree ;-)

Comment: Reference [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @minitech. I didn't realise python supported +=, or -=.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tuple unpacking is pythonic, but some other parts of your snippet aren't. Here's a slight modification using a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to avoid (and separate) the string concatenation:

```
def fib(k=100):
    """ Generate fibonacci numbers up to k. """
    a, b = 1, 2
    while a <= k:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(' '.join(map(str, fib())))
# prints: '1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89'
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is pythonic. In fact, Raymond Hettinger talks about this in his excellent talk, [Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python](http://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go). It's a good talk to watch if you're interested in writing pythonic code.

To answer your second question, I like to read the source of the [python standard library](http://hg.python.org/cpython/branches). Most of the modules are very well written, as you might expect. The `collections` module, for example, is nice to read.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the resources @jme